# Please consider these minor improvements to the new comment flagging modal

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, comment-flags

A new comment flagging modal just [went live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313436/253521):

[image]

Aside from the fact that now it doesn't match the other flagging/closure modals in design (something that will likely be changed in the future...), I've already noticed a few things that, while minor, I don't like about it that I think could be improved.

- It suffers from the new-age "animated is good" problem. Specifically, the 100ms transition feels slow and jarring and I would like to see it removed (yes, I know I can do this with a user script, but it would improve the responsiveness of the site and reduce their code base size by getting rid of this effect)
- When inspecting it, I see the z-index value is set to 9000. This should be changed to 2 or something more semantic (Stack Exchange sites don't have elements on 9000 different z-indices, last I checked). In fact, changing it to 2 on my own didn't make it disappear behind other stuff. Some other modals may interfere, though, so 5 or 10 would be a safer bet than 2.
- The middle flag option is now named "It's not relevant". I'm sure someone complained about this phrasing in the past when new comment reasons have been demo'd, but lots of comments that are relevant should still be removed. There was nothing wrong with the previous name of "No longer needed"... can we please have that phrasing back, or at least keep the spirit of it with "Not needed"? As it stands, "It's not relevant" is factually incorrect in some cases *and* repeated in the longer subheading.

Comment: Chat flag dialog, or comment flag dialog? Because if that is a chat flag dialog then there are some other wording issues in need of addressing...

Comment: Look at the z index of the left sidebar

Comment: We use high z-indices a few places.  Question flagging is 3000 and suggested edits are 8951.  9000 comes from the process of standardizing the values while working around the existing CSS/JavaScript. That specific number represents the `.z-modal` class in our LESS.

Comment: @Shog9 Dear gods, it's everywhere

Comment: @BrianNickel You can and should reduce those by two factors, at least.

Comment: I for one, really prefer NLN to NLR.... sometimes relevant comments are no longer needed ._.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371870/how-do-the-new-comment-flags-affect-our-comments?cb=1 cc @BrianNickel re: the wording change for 'No longer needed' to 'not relevant'

Comment: @BrianNickel the high z-index does indeed have repercussions, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313581/391802

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On August 8th the Flag dialog was changed to the below design:

[image: New flag dialog options]

"It's not relevant" is now:

> #### It's no longer needed.
>
> This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post.

Although it's also now missing the serial (Oxford) comma it had before... our work is never finished, it seems :-)

The other two errors mentioned in my question can be fixed purely with user styles to remove the slow animation and use a more sensible z-index value.

Answer (score 7):

How about this:

> #### Why are you flagging this comment?
>
> - It's rude or abusive.
> - It's off-topic or unrelated to this post.
> - It's outdated, obsolete or not relevant anymore.
> - Something else.

In other words, I'd split the middle option into "This is not at all relevant" versus "This used to be relevant but now it isn't."

Answer (score 5):

Instead of **Its Not Relevant** just have it say: **Should be Removed**  everything else can stay.

This wording gets right to the point: the flagging user believes that the comment is not adding value and should be removed.  Nothing more needs to be said, and no reasoning inferred for the flag.  If it does then they can use the Something else option.

Comment: I like this wording. It's more neutral and surely "nicer" than telling the user his comment is irrelevant

Comment: Although this naming doesn't really **guide** users (or mods handling the flags) in any way, and might draw too many flags away from the other reasons (especially in cases which require explanation). It can mean anything from "This is obsolete" to "this is rude" to "this is a spoiler" to even just "I don't like this". If we go this route, we might as well just replace the entire dialog with a giant "Should be removed" button.

Comment: @Dukeling - Thats kinda the point most flags are pretty obvious.  I dont like this by itself is not a reason to flag or delete a comment.  Chances are there are valid reason to delete any given comment that gets flagged though.

Comment: Doesn't "Should be removed" also apply to rude and abusive comments?

Comment: @E.P. Yes, but rude and abusive comments entail an entirely extra set of responses from moderators and/or staff than comments that are just chatty or obsolete. Temporal comments getting removed don't require extra actions; someone running around flaming other users in comments does.

Comment: @TylerH Yes but if the idea is to hit that golden phrasing that precisely describes what that button should be used for then it also shouldn't be so broad as to encompass everything.

Comment: Unless the intent of the change is to allow for comment chat it needs to be broad enough to encompass comments that are just chat

Comment: @E.P. I agree, hence the third bullet point of my question above.