# Comment flag thank you note z-index

Tags: bug, design, comment-flags

Today I stumbled upon another issue with the thank you notice that pops up after flagging a comment: When you don't click that notice away and scroll down, that notice will go *over* the header nav. I highly doubt that this is intended.

[image: notice is over header nav]

It is obviously not a high priority issue but nevertheless I wanted to report that. I'm not sure if this is the right place for that, but seeing some other recent posts about the new comment flagging change, I thought why not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please consider these minor improvements to the new comment flagging modal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313438/please-consider-these-minor-improvements-to-the-new-comment-flagging-modal)

Comment: Not to mention that the green Thanks modal will appear in random spots on the screen. For me it appears in the top-right half the time...

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate to me, particularly given a lack of instruction from SE to post all bug reports in a single Q/A.