# "No longer needed" flags still continue to show up as "not relevant" in my flag history, even after the name change was reverted

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags, flag-history

Today, the change that modified the name of the "no longer needed" comment flag to "not relevant" [was reverted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313687/377214). When flagging a comment, the option now shows as "no longer needed".

However, after submitting the flag, I checked my flag history, and that flag still shows as "not relevant". Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313689/the-mod-dashboard-is-still-showing-not-relevant-for-comment-flags