# Do not show comment flags in "declined in last 7 days" view

Tags: feature-request, bug, flag-history, flag-ban

I went to check my flag history, only to see this big banner:

> [image: You are currently banned from flagging - view flags declined in the last 7 days.]

I clicked on the button, and saw eight declined flags. Five of those were comment flags, which [do not count towards bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/377214) ([reconfirmed today by Shog](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7158012#7158012)).

I was testing out [bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313688/no-longer-needed-flags-still-continue-to-show-up-as-not-relevant-in-my-flag) in the new comment flagging functionality in order to [report them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313754/updated-comment-flagging-supporting-the-new-code-of-conduct/313756#313756), and initially thought that the declined comment flags (you can't retract comment flags) were the ones that caused me to get banned. However, according to the above links, this isn't the case.

Can we exclude comment flags from the view triggered by the banner, since those don't count towards bans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like this misses the point of the warning, which is to examine your declined flags to see if you can identify areas where your communication is ineffective.

...and *not* to identify areas in which miscommunication is ok.

Comment: Can we find some way to make it clear to users that their comment flags weren't considered towards the ban? I got confused because the majority of my flags declined with the last seven days were comment flags.

Comment: Also, you can't see which comment you flagged, just the post.

Comment: yeah... The flag summary for comment flags is kinda awful. THAT is a problem worth solving. Somehow.