# NLN flag description should have an Oxford comma

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, comment-flags, grammar

[Company guidance](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#commas) says to "Use the oxford [sic] comma in sentences."* However, the description of the "It's no longer needed." flag, from the flag modal, says "This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post." - i.e., it lacks an Oxford comma. This should be brought in line with the company's grammar guidelines.**

I have found a [previous post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313859/1017231) which mentioned this, but only as a bit of jest in an answer focused elsewhere.

*<sub>Amusingly, this guidance itself is a bit incorrect, as it should properly be the ["Oxford" comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)</sub>

**<sub>Yes, this is very nitpicky. But I like Oxford commas :)</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And so it is done :) For some time translations may be missing - changing the text (adding a comma) means that the text needs to be translated again.