# Comment flag reasons with the link to CoC

Tags: support, comments, flags, code-of-conduct

What is the reason to separate the first two items in the comment flagging popup? This sepation makes me to think hard is I choosed the correct one.

Furthermore, just imagine that the user has selected "unfriendy" option instead of the "harassment" one or vice-versa, will that flag be rejected by the moderator?

> [image: flagging]

Comment: Related: [Updated comment flagging - Supporting the new Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313754) and [What will the comment flag dialog look like after our new CoC has been shipped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313552)

Comment: I wonder if the first reason carries a heavier sentence if accepted. Like when answers are flagged as abusive and the poster gets a -100 rep penalty.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter that much *which* of these reasons you choose if the comment is flag-worthy. Having two separate CoC based flag reasons merely makes it clearer what kind of behaviour is not welcome on Stack Exchange: clearly, attacks and harassment are absolutely unacceptable. But condescending behaviour has no place here as well, even when it doesn't rise to the intensity of abusive behaviour.

Selecting the more suitable flag reason does make it easier for mods to confirm or reject the flag. E.g. it is clearly wrong to flag a comment as abusive when it merely asks “What do the docs say?”. But it could merit a flag as “unfriendly”, depending on context. Note that if context is very important for why a comment was flagged, then explaining this with a custom flag reason is often the better choice.