# "Contains harrassment, bigotry, or abuse" vs "Unfriendly or unkind" vs "Rude or abusive"

Tags: support, comment-flags

I noticed posts only have one "offensive" flag, but comments have 2. What is the purpose of there being an "Unfriendly or unkind" separate from "Harassment, bigotry, or abuse." To me they mean the same thing, inappropriate, offensive comments that are unwelcome and maybe their authors need to be warned or banned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What distinguishes 'harassment, abuse, and bigotry' and 'unfriendly or unkind', and is it ever appropriate to flag one after the other is declined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331245/what-distinguishes-harassment-abuse-and-bigotry-and-unfriendly-or-unkind)