# Is the flagging message "we take your reports seriously" generic or specific?

Tags: discussion, flags, user-interface

I created this account about a year ago, and have been flagging things steadily (if infrequently) since then. After I submit a flag, I get a pop-up reading

> Thanks for flagging! We take your reports seriously.

I could just be forgetting, but I don't think I saw that message after my first few flags. This leads me to wonder, what does "we take your reports seriously" mean in the flagging UI?

Has it been there for a while, and I just never noticed? Is it a generic reassurance, added in [the Jul 2018 UI update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313436/), that the system and mods take the community's flags seriously? Or is it a message shown to only specific users, letting them know that their particular flags are taken more seriously than average, as sort of a spiritual successor to flag weight?

Comment: I think it's shown to all users for all flags, but I'm not totally sure. At least for comment flags, I've seen the message every time.

Comment: If memory serves the flag used to just say "thanks for flagging", and had a very different look and feel (a red popup right next to the comment you flagged).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a recent update from Stack Exchange, so **this message is generic**.

The change applies *only to comments* and was announced in this post:

[Updated comment flagging - Supporting the new Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313754/364003)

> In addition to this, a thank you response [toast notification](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11998/what-is-a-toast-notification) was added when a user flags a comment to show appreciation for that flag - and in the case of unwelcoming or abusive flags, an apology for the comment. The implementation for this is still being moved over to the Stacks styling, see [this related answer on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372099/4548692) for more information.

Comment: I thought I was special :(

Answer (score 4):

Feedback on comment flags changed a few months ago as part of a reworking of the UI for comment flags.  Everybody sees this message (with the green background, near the top of the frame) when flagging a comment; even moderators see it.  (Why would a moderator flag comments instead of just deleting them?  Sometimes we do it for auditing purposes, particularly for rude comments.)

Flagging a post produces a "thanks, we'll look into it" message (blue background, next to the "flag" control) for everybody.